# How to return data to page before?

Tags: php

Hi i wanted to make registration form. 
but i don't know how to return data if the data failed after i click submit.
the data became empty so i wanted to restore before user click submit.

```
 <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="doregister.php">
 <input type="text" name="txtnama" id="txtnama" />
 <textarea name="txtalamat" id="txtalamat" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
 <input type="submit" name="txtsubmit" id="txtsubmit" value="Submit" />
 <input type="reset" name="txtreset" id="txtreset" value="Reset" />
 </form>
```

here the picture:
http://tinypic.com/r/160sopk/5

Thanks in advance for any help, and I'm really sorry if this has been asked before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put back the posted values:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="doregister.php">
  <input type="text" name="txtnama" id="txtnama"<?php echo (isset($_POST['txtnama'])) ? ' value="'.$_POST['txtnama'].'"' : '') ?>" />
  <textarea name="txtalamat" id="txtalamat" cols="30" rows="5"><?php echo (isset($_POST['txtalamat'] ? $_POST['txtalamat'] : '')) ?></textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="txtsubmit" id="txtsubmit" value="Submit" />
  <input type="reset" name="txtreset" id="txtreset" value="Reset" />
</form>
```

If `doregister.php` is another page, you should check the values in the current page then redirect to `doregister.php` if ok.

Answer (score 1):

Just echo out the value from each element in the POST array into the `value` attribute of the `input` tag. Make sure you also check if it's set or not empty first before echoing them out, else you'll probably get some error notices

```
<input type="text" name="txtnama" id="txtnama" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['txtnama'])){ echo $_POST['txtnama']; } ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

As has already been said by Glide and Kemal, that's how to do it.

I seperate them a bit by setting the variable at the top of the page:

`$txtnama = (isset($_POST['txtnama']) ? $_POST['txtnama'] : '');`

Then including it in the form:

`<input type="text" name="txtnama" value="<?php echo $txtnama; ?>" />`

I prefer this as it feels less cluttered amongst the HTML. Also, when I create an 'edit' form, I can use the same form and just put this at the top:

```
$txtnama = (isset($_POST['txtnama']) ? $_POST['txtnama'] : ($customer->txtnama!='' ? $customer->txtnama: ''));
```

to set the value to the database value if the form hasn't already been submitted.